# MongoDb update a field in a huge collection using pymongo fast

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have an 13GB of documents in a collection in mongoDB where I need to update a field ip_address. The original value and the replacement values are given in excel sheet. I am looping through each value from excel and updating it using:

```
old_value={"ip_address":original_value}
new_value={"$set":{"ip_address":replacement_value}
tableConnection.update_many(old_value,new_value)
```

In order to process 1 update it is taking over 2 minutes. I have 1500 updates to do. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: I have not used it, but I'm wondering if `Bulk()` operations might provide some efficiencies.

Comment: create a index for `ip_address` first

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes.. That's what i am looking at. Will update once I find a better way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk operations won't speed up your updates by much; the best way to achieve a performance increase is to add an index. This can be as simple as:

```
db.collection.createIndex({'ip_address': 1})
```

Refer to the documentation regarding potential blocking on certain older versions of the database https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/

The index will take up addtional storage; if that is an issue you can delete the index once you've completed the updates.

Comment: Great, It worked. I used the bulk_write(). It took 9 mins to perform 6 updates earlier it would take 11-12 mins.  indexing took some time but now all the operations are instantaneous.

Comment: The size  of collection increased from 13.5gb to 14.4 gb after adding index

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the above answer given by Belly Buster the syntax to perform indexing and bulk_write in PyMongo that worked for me is :

```
db.collection.create_index("ip_address")

requests = [UpdateMany({'ip_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx'}, {'$set': {'ip_address':'yy.yy.yy.yy'}}),[UpdateMany({'ip_address': 'xx.xx.xx.xx'}, {'$set': {'ip_address':'yy.yy.yy.yy'}})]
try :
      db.collection.bulk_write(requests, ordered=False)
except BulkWriteError as bwe: 
      print(bwe)
```